how to install turtlebot3-gazebo on ubuntu24.04 using ROS2 jazzy
I would like to start learning Navigation2, but I've encountered some trouble.
I use ubuntu24.04,ROS2 jazzy
But When I started following the instructions in https://docs.nav2.org/getting_started/index.html
I found "Install the Turtlebot 3 packages (Humble and older):"
I exec :sudo apt install ros-jazzy-turtlebot3-gazebo
but got:Unable to locate package ros-jazzy-turtlebot3-gazebo
So,how can I solve this problem?

There is no ros2 jazzy for turtlebot3 simulation yet. You must try with older version of ubuntu or on a virtual machine.

Thanks,is there any plane to suport ros2 jazzy?
